# serial port via minicom: can minicom use line-editing (i.e. readline functionality)?

Tags: serial-port, readline, minicom

I am successfully talking to a board connected over a serial port interface to my PC. I can both send and receive bytes - but for interactive applications executing on the board, that try to read inputs from their stdin, minicom doesn't seem to offer any kind of *readline*-like editing functionality:

```
// code running on the embedded board
printf("Reading a number: ")
scanf("%d", &i);
```

In minicom:

```
$ minicom -D /dev/ttyS0 -b 38400
...
Reading a number: 1a^H
```

Once I enter an 'a', I can't backspace over it.

Note there's no shell or anything in between here - this is plain minicom over a serial line, nothing more.

`screen /dev/ttyS0 38400` seems to work fine - allowing me to edit the line and only sending it to the serial when I press ENTER.

Can minicom be configured to do the same?

Comment: `screen` does its own line buffering, `minicom` doesn't. If the application on your board you're talking to doesn't offer that kind of line editing, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `rlwrap` to add readline's advanced line editing features to any simple terminal program. I'm not sure if `minicom` would work fine with it since it features quite a complex UI; if not, try `picocom`.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt install socat rlwrap
rlwrap --  socat  -  /dev/ttyUSB1,crnl
```

Then you can use C-R for search, arrows for Next/Prev commands, Alt-b, Alt-f, C-A, C-e, arrows for navigation within a line,  etc.